# minikube + Docker Volumes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-volume, minikube

With regular native Docker on Mac, without minikube, I can take the official example from https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume

run:

```
docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  --mount source=myvol2,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

Then I can run `docker inspect devtest` and see that the mount was created:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "volume",
        "Name": "myvol2",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol2/_data",
        "Destination": "/app",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
    }
],
```

I can run `docker volume ls` and see `myvol2`

If I am using the latest minikube, currently v0.22.3, with a fresh minikube local VM:

```
minikube delete
rm -rf ~/.kube 
rm -rf ~/.minikube 
minikube start

Starting local Kubernetes v1.7.5 cluster...
```

Then use the minikube VM version of Docker with `eval $(minikube docker-env)`, then repeat the same command from earlier:

```
docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  --mount source=myvol2,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

Then `docker inspect devtest` comes back with an empty mounts section: `"Mounts": []`. and `docker volume ls` shows no `myvol2`. In other words, the Docker volumes seem to simply not work with minikube.

FYI, here is the output of `docker version` when working with Minikube v0.22.3:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Tue Sep  5 20:12:06 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24 (minimum version )
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Wed Jan 11 00:23:16 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Comment: did you try to manually create volume after `eval $(minikube docker-env)` with `docker volume create test1` ? I can see it. Currently I'm searching how to use docker volume in Pod.

Comment: Yes, that `docker volume create` seems to work fine, but the volume auto create in `docker run` does not.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3001#issuecomment-446055883 may be the answer.  Volume should be in minikube env in this case. As they mention in the link above:

> So you have to mount your folder(host) into minikube(vm) first (use `minikube mount`), so the docker can access it.